# How to use Toast when I cant use "this" as context

Tags: java, android, toast

I have a location listener activity and I want to make toast notifications. But it will not let me pass `this` as the context. How should I make toast work?

Comment: Can you post the activity code and the error message? You should be able to get a valid context from within an Activity.

Comment: `The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (mylocationlistener, String, int)`

Comment: I have decided that I will make the locationlistener a sub class in the activity

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the toast is located inside your activity class, you could use `YourActiviy.this` where `YourActivity` is the class name. If it's outside your class, you'll need to get your activity context (pass it in the constructor etc).

Comment: Makes sense. For example, in my situation, the solution below is similar to what he described above: `Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Pressed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 7):

If you are in the inner Class then try this also

> getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 5):

You can use `NameOfYourActivity.this`

For example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

 ...
     Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, text, duration).show();
```

Comment: the activity is a `locationlistener` so it gives the error The method `makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (mylocationlistener, String, int)`

Comment: @Seth - locationlistener is not an activity.

Comment: You should paste your code to your OP , it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you have a listener with a method called "onComplete" inside it, this code should work.

```
public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        final String response_complete = response;
        MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, text, duration).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

instead try getApplicationContext()

```
 Toast tea = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Send", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 tea.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Field variable:  `Context context;`

inside OnCreate:  `context = this;`

Xamarin / C# Syntax:
`Toast.MakeText(context, "your message", ToastLength.Long).Show();`

Android / Java syntax:
`Toast.makeText(context, "your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are in an inner class in the Activity. If thats the case, try ActivityName.this.